Is this post really off-topic?

I have a question about my Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange post: What is the best type of antenna and cable for my project?
It is deleted because of:
Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Closed 16 days ago.

This post was edited and submitted for review 8 days ago and failed to reopen the post:

Original close reason(s) were not resolved

But that's wrong! In the first place, the reason for closure was not met except by title, and after the correction even the title was completely not relevant to this reason! Can you find anything here that seems to fall within the scope of this expansion?

You are not asking a design question, which is what this site's Q&A is centered around. SE also does not like shopping type questions (Jeff Atwood is quite clear on that here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)
The problem with this question is it isn't framed as a design question, and we have no idea exactly what kind of protocols, voltage levels distances (you list two, which one did you want?) ect. We also don't know what line drivers you have and single ended/differential signaling you have. We aren't going to select a cable for you, because we can't. If you want to describe exactly what you want to do with your design, we can tell you if it will work or not or help you along where you are stuck.

But I am asking design question and this is not shopping question and it is still saying recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them Why?! What do you mean with "framed as a design question"? and we have no idea exactly what kind of protocols, voltage levels distances (you list two, which one did you want?) ect. That's not true, because I say, that I am using ESP32 CAM Module and this will explain everything of those! Just look at little internet and every of these specs will find easily.

@DoctorThumb Please note that your intentions and the way they are perceived may differ. You should've taken the hint and rephrased your question so that it sounded less like a shopping type question and more like a design question.

That has the makings of an excellent question BUT you failed to make changes that significantly altered it from a shopping question.
In a comment in reply to:

"You'll get better advice if you ask for overall design ideas rather than cable and antenna recommendations"

you said

"Okay then, please everyone respond also like this."

Saying that in a comment and then adding two words to your subject line is not an appropriate response.
Rather than saying HOW you wish to solve the problem you should describe what the problem is that you are attempting to solve. You can also ad some "how" ideas of your own, but they should be secondary to the problem description and query.
I can give you some very good answer, but the question needs to suit the groups rules. This is not just pedantry - if the system is to be maintained we cannot allow the vast number of special cases that people would want us to allow.
Meta is not the place for technical answers, but if it were [[ :-)]] I might ask why you wish to use CAT6 to carry WiFi when it is never used for that, why you do not instead placing the transmitter and maybe it's power supply at the surface with zero RF cable length, ... . You need to describe required data rate and content IN THE QUESTION (not in comments). Where you are affects allowed power levels and frequency bands - but most countries will have somewhere suitable - but we need to know in case better alternatives may apply.
Tell us as much as you know re the technical and functional needs. We can help. But, you'll need a substantial rewording.
